# Swift StoreKIt has unresolved identifier in the payment queue

Tags: switch-statement, swift, payment, storekit

I'm getting an unresolved identifier in my swift adaptation of a payment queue on each of the case statements. When I log trans.transactionState, I get "(Enum Value)" on every turn of the transaction for loop. I need some fresh eyes. Any ideas?

```
 func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: AnyObject[]!)    {
    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
        switch trans.transactionState {
                case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                    self.openLevel2();
                    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)
                    break;
                case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)
                    break;
                case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                    //[self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                default:
                    break;
            }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write `.Purchased` instead of `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased`. The type gets inferred automatically. Alternatively you could also write `SKPaymentTransactionState.Purchased`.